# Turn on num lock permanently

Tags: keyboard

I would like to have my num-lock turned on permanently. I never turn it off. But every once in a while it gets turned off. Is there any way to do this in Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.10.?

Comment: Could be a bad idea.  Num-lock and Caps-lock are handy/quick indicators for checking the severity of a PC hang or freeze.  I.E. if the PC fails to respond to X-lock presses by toggling its keyboard LED, then the PC is really hosed.

Comment: In that case you've got capslock and scroll lock to test with..?

Comment: The failure to toggle the LEDs does not necessarily mean the PC is hosed. What an extraordinary statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**For windows**

Have numlock [activate on startup with a VBS script](https://web.archive.org/web/20100210142901/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314879)

[create a custom layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665) with MSKLC with numlock disabled

**For linux**

[Enable numlock at boot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock)

[disable key with xmodmap](http://www.xfree86.org/4.2.0/xmodmap.1.html)

Comment: I don't think MSKLC will allow you to disable a modifier key. I remember being unable to use it to disable caps lock...

Comment: you cannot disable numlock in MSKLC v1.4

Comment: the first link is dead

Comment: replaced it with a contemporary archive.org link

Answer (score 3):

I compiled a usable solution to this. Using a `.reg` file I turn the numlock key on at boot, as well as disable the numlock key in the keyboard mappings.

The file looks like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Keyboard]
"InitialKeyboardIndicators"="2147483650"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,45,00,00,00,00,00
```

More about the background is [on my blog](http://atornblad.se/keep-numlock-on-permanently).

Comment: At last the answer for this questions! I wish I could make your answer useful 10 times!

Comment: Now how do I use this to permanently turn it off?